# Windows Update - Schrödinger's KB

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

So I am trying to install Atmel Studio 7 on a Windows 7 SP1 machine. Atmel Studio requires SHA-2 signing to be compatible with Windows 10, therefore requiring SHA-2 support on earlier operating systems as well. For Windows 7 SP1 this is added through KB3033929, and as part of the installation process Atmel Studio checks for this KB. This is where it gets fun...

- Atmel Studio 7 detects KB3033929 as missing, providing a link to the microsoft webpage to download and install manually.
- Running the .msu downloaded from microsoft and it claims the update is already installed.
- Update is not showing in installed updates
- When attempting to uninstall update using .msu, WUSI claims update is not installed.

So microsoft is claiming it is both installed and not installed simultaneously. See the two screenshots for proof. [Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHehZ.png) and then [not installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S74ru.png)

Is there any way to definitively check whether it is installed, and if so how to get it to recognise as installed reliably.

Comment: Sounds like the patch has been superseded, contact the publisher of the application, and ask the for an installer that works

Comment: Great title! The first thing I'd do is check under `Control Panel` -> `Programs and Features` to see if it is installed. You will need to select `Show updates`: I have a feeling this was a check-box in Win7, but I can't remember exactly. If it's there, try uninstalling from here. Otherwise, you'll need to change settings in the registry, though I'd perform an integrity check. There are a number of third-party uninstallers, many of the freeware, which may get rid of the inconsistency for you. Failing that, use `regedit` to remove every reference to `KB3033929`, eg by renaming to `BK3033929`.

Comment: have you tried the DISM workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the MSU (with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)), open a CMD.exe as admin and run

```
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows6.1-KB3033929-x64.cab
```

this skips the check if the update is required or not. Now try to install Atmel Studio.

Comment: This has worked exactly as desired. Seems to be an issue with the current version of Atmel Studio and Windows 7 so your workaround was enough to let the installer run. Thank You.

Comment: the installer checks for a specific KB and not for the file versions. If the update gets replaced (superseded), the disk cleanup can remove it to shrink WinSxS. And now the installer can't find the update.

Answer (score 0):

Atmel has an official answer to this situation in their [knowledge base](http://atmel.force.com/support/articles/en_US/FAQ/Atmel-Studio-7-installer-is-blocked-by-non-availability-of-KB3033929-in-Windows-7-x64).

The TL;DR version is that the installer has a "secret" command-line argument that converts the blocking error into a non-blocking warning. Copied from the link above:

```
as-installer-7.0.1188-web.exe /SystemValidationErrorAsWarning
```

It is documented for the "internet-connected" installer, but I just used it successfully with the "fully predownloaded" installer - as-installer-7.0.1188-full.exe.

Comment: Thanks, nice to see Atmel has officially acknowledged it and provided a workaround now. Especially useful given I have to install it again soon.