# Can't connect to Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8.1, windows-update

I couldn't connect to Windows Update nor install .NET so I've done a clean install of Windows 8.1 from Microsoft's iso.

The same problem occurs : the loading bar is never beginning ! No error message.

I've compared what is happening on my Win 7 netbook with Wireshark. When searching for updates, it's sending http requests to Microsoft with a URL like `/v11/2/microsoftupdate/`. The fresh install of Win 8.1 basically doesn't try to connect anywhere.

I have no proxy, no firewall, no special configuration. Both laptops are on the same network.

Comment: If you don't choose to update during installation, the process will not attempt to access the update web-site. After the installation completes, you should then be able to connect to the internet and install updates.

Comment: Do you have any problems connecting to the Internet on that computer?  How are you accessing Windows Update (from the Windows application menu)?  What loading bar are you referring to (does it identify updates but doesn't download them or are you referring to something else)?

Comment: @AFH the installation is done. I'm speaking of what occurs after.

Comment: @fixer1234 no problem to connect to the internet with a regular browser. I'm trying to use Windows Update (and add .NET framework) from the control panel. The loading bar of update search is going from left to right forever. It doesn't identify update nor say there is nothing to download.

Comment: Here are a couple of things to check. (1) Browse to http://www.windowsupdate.com/v11/2/microsoftupdate/: you should get error 403 - Access denied. (2) Ping http://www.windowsupdate.com: this should show the same IP address as you see as the destination IP in your WireShark log.

Comment: @AFH you get something here. I get the 403 error, but ping does not find the host.

Comment: Sorry, with “www.”, the host is associated with an IP (not pingable).

Comment: No, I don't get a response either, but I do get the IP: is it the same as in the WireShark log?

Comment: install this update and try again: http://superuser.com/a/1131623/174557

Comment: @AFH no, my Win 7 netbook get http answers from 88.221.83.41. The ping made from my Win 8.1 laptop indicates 65.55.50.189.

Comment: @magicandre1981 it can't install : i get a window called "setup of windows update in autonomous mode", and a loading bar called "searching for updates on this computer" (homemade translations from french). The loading bar goes from left to right forever (it's been sth like half an hour now).

Comment: stop WU service before doing the double click on the MSU: http://superuser.com/a/1044548/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 I had done this :(

Comment: use DISm to install the update: http://superuser.com/a/1144406/174557 (change the names to the correct CAB) this skips the check if the update is needed or not.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks a lot, it has worked ! Would you like to submit your answer to earn reputation ?

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Sorry if I took you down any blind alleys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the `Windows Update` Service (via [services.msc](http://computerstepbystep.com/windows_update_service.html) or in a cmd.exe which is started as admin via `net stop wuauserv` - [this improves speed of installing the MSU update](https://superuser.com/a/1044548/174557) which you have to download), download and install this update by double click on the MSU:

**[Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102812)**

If the hack to stop Wu service doesn't speedup install of the MSU, extract the MSU with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and use DISM to install the update.

```
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows8.1-KB3102812-x64.cab
```

This skips the check if the update is required and works around the hang at "Searching for updates on this computer" while installing a MSU.

Do a reboot and check again for new updates. Now Windows Update will work and show new updates in a few minutes.